# why I get max_weights=1 after gradient check?

Tags: backpropagation

I set a 3 layers neural network,it has 2 hidden layers,But when I try to implement gradient check ,I got my max_weigh=1 ,which means I have some error in my backprop.here are my backprop function,I really need some help
is there something wrong with my codes?
thanks!

```
def loss(self,X,y,reg = 0.0):
    #forward prop
    W1, b1 = self.params['W1'], self.params['b1']
    W2, b2 = self.params['W2'], self.params['b2']
    W3, b3 = self.params['W3'], self.params['b3']
    N,D = X.shape
    H1out = np.maximum(0,X.dot(W1)+b1)        #H1out (N,H1)
    H2out = np.maximum(0,H1out.dot(W2)+b2)    #H2out (N,H2)
    scores = None
    scores = H2out.dot(W3)+b3
    scores_shift = scores-np.max(scores,axis = 1).reshape(-1,1)
    softmaxout = np.exp(scores_shift)/np.sum(np.exp(scores_shift),axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
    loss_main = None
    loss = None
    loss_main = -np.sum(np.log(softmaxout[range(N),list(y)]))
    loss = loss_main/N + reg*np.sum(W1*W1)*np.sum(
            W2*W2)+np.sum(W3*W3)

    #backward prop
    dscores = softmaxout.copy()               #dscores (N,C)
    dscores[range(N),list(y)] -= 1
    dscores /= N

    dW3 = H2out.T.dot(dscores)
    db3 = np.sum(dscores,axis = 0)

    dh2 = dscores.dot(W3.T)                   #dh2 (N,H2)
    dh_Relu2 = (H2out > 0) * dh2              #dh_ReLu2 (N,H2)
    dW2 = H1out.T.dot(dh_Relu2)
    db2 = np.sum(dh_Relu2,axis = 0)

    dh1 = dh_Relu2.dot(W2.T)                  #dh1 (N,H1)
    dh_Relu1 = (H1out>0) * dh1
    dW1 = X.T.dot(dh_Relu1)
    db1 = np.sum(dh_Relu1,axis = 0)

    grad = {}
    grad['W1'] = dW1
    grad['b1'] = db1
    grad['W2'] = dW2
    grad['b2'] = db2
    grad['W3'] = dW3
    grad['b3'] = db3

    return loss,grad
```

Comment: the active function i use is RELU, and i get loss from softmax